# Difficulty with middle click - MS Wireless 6000 scroll wheel sensitivity

Tags: mouse, autohotkey, wireless-mouse, autoit

(Microsoft Windows)

When I try to middle click on the scroll wheel, I usually just get a little bit of scrolling instead.   I am using the **Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 6000**, which is very sensitive to small scrolling movements (the wheel doesn't ever click--it's got continuous, fine-grained scrolling).

Is there a way to change the sensitivity of the scroll wheel, so that I can middle click more easily with the mouse wheel?  For now I switched the thumb button to middle click, but I would much rather use that button for something else.

I believe the the software configuration is not adequate, since I looked at it -- so I probably need a workaround.  I would accept answers that include AutoHotKey or AutoIt solutions, and the like.

Comment: This should be a simple matter of changing the mouse scroll speed in your operating system. If you provide more details, such as which OS you use, we can provide more information.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe, I currently have Windows 10 installed, but I can't remember which OS I was using when I asked this question 5 years ago--it might have been either Ubuntu Linux or Windows.  I rarely use this mouse anymore--I can't recall the last time I used it.   My struggle wasn't with scroll speed--it's a different kind of sensitivity since the scroll wheel is smooth/continuous (it doesn't click when you scroll it).  I do not wish to adjust the sensitivity to make it scroll less--I wish for a threshold before it registers any scrolling.

Comment: In the absence of notches with the scroll wheel, this normally comes down to the individual mouse and it's associated configuration software. If you provide some information on which mouse you're using, we can proceed.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe the mouse description is in the title of the question.  "In the absence of notches..." --> that is why I added the tag "autohotkey", because I hoped it would offer a workaround.  I am not sure why you removed it, because it made sense from my perspective--I probably have to use a workaround because the software configuration for the mouse does not afford an easy solution.

Comment: Hmm.  It was 5 years ago, but since I requested workarounds using AutoHotKey, it must have been on Windows.  Sorry for the confusion earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Given the new info in the comments, and ruling out whatever mouse is currently used as having software that would acceptably modify scroll wheel threshold sensitivity, I can only recommend Autohotkey to assist here.

```
Speed = 1

WheelUp::MouseClick, WheelUp, , , %Speed%
WheelDown::MouseClick, WheelDown, , , %Speed%
```

AHK's documentation isn't the best, so while they suggest speed progresses from 0 (fastest) to 100 (slowest), I find the reverse, where 1 is fastest, and 100 is slowest, so I suggest experimenting to see which works.